# pyparsing input to and specific output

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm thinking how to parse the following input:

```
comment ='  @Class wordinfo dict<<position:int>,wordinfo:str>\n ' + \
                           '@Class instances dict<<word:str>,instances:atomicint> '
```

To a specific output:

```
{'wordinfo': {'columns': [('wordinfo', 'text')],
              'primary_keys': [('position', 'int')],
              'type': 'StorageDict'},

 'instances': {'columns': [('instances', 'counter')],
               'primary_keys': [('word', 'text')],
               'type': 'StorageDict'}
}
```

As we can see above, I need to take the key of the dictionary as a primary key and then I can have one or more values as a columns, first I always have the variable name and then the variable type.I'm asking myself if there's some basic way to get the result I want since I'm not an expert with pyparsing. It is feasible? What will be the steps I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to write a BNF. You are already started with this thinking, when you wrote: *I need to take the key of the dictionary as a primary key and then I can have one or more values as a columns, first I always have the variable name and then the variable type.*

Convert this to something more formal:

```
class_definition :: '@Class' identifier class_body
class_body :: class_dict  // can add other types here as necessary
class_dict :: 'dict' '<' '<' identifier ':' value_type '>' ','
                     column_decl [',' column_decl]... '>'
column_decl :: identifier ':' value_type
value_type :: 'int' | 'str' | 'atomicint'
```

Hmmm, `identifier : value_type` is in a couple of places, let's call that `var_decl` and rewrite. Also, I think it is possible for you to have compound primary keys, by defining a comma-separated list inside the `<>`s, and we use this kind of list in a couple of places.  Rewriting:

```
class_definition :: '@Class' identifier class_body
class_body :: class_dict  // can add other types here as necessary
class_dict :: 'dict' '<' '<' vars_decl '>' ',' vars_decl '>'
vars_decl :: var_decl [',' var_decl]...
var_decl :: identifier ':' value_type
value_type :: 'int' | 'str' | 'atomicint'
```

Then work from the bottom-up to define these in pyparsing terms:

```
import pyparsing as pp
S = pp.Suppress
identifier = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier
value_type = pp.oneOf("int str atomicint")
var_decl = pp.Group(identifier + S(":") + value_type)
vars_decl = pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(var_decl))
dict_decl = pp.Group(S("dict") + S("<") 
                     + S("<") + vars_decl + S(">") + S(",")
                     + vars_decl 
                     + S(">"))
class_decl = pp.Group('@Class' + identifier + dict_decl)
```

And finally, drop in results names so that you can pick out the different pieces more easily after parsing:

```
import pyparsing as pp
S = pp.Suppress
identifier = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier
value_type = pp.oneOf("int str atomicint")
var_decl = pp.Group(identifier("name") + S(":") + value_type("type"))
vars_decl = pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(var_decl))
dict_decl = pp.Group(S("dict") + S("<") 
                     + S("<") + vars_decl("primary_key") + S(">") + S(",")
                     + vars_decl("columns") 
                     + S(">"))
class_decl = pp.Group('@Class'
                      + identifier("class_name")
                      + dict_decl("class_body"))
```

Then parse your text using:

```
class_definitions = pp.OneOrMore(class_decl).parseString(comment)
```

And print out what you got:

```
print(class_definitions.dump())
```

Or even better:

```
class_decl.runTests(comment)
```

This is completely untested, may be a mismatched paren in there, but that is the general idea. But even if you end up using something other than pyparsing, *start with the BNF*. It will really help clarify your thinking, and general concept of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, i'm testing it and i will add more different data types, this clarifies a lot what i have to do!